# What's the best way to handle not being able to send a private message to a user?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm working on a discord bot that uses private messages to inform a user if they've been warned by a moderator. While working on this, I discovered that there is an edge case where a bot can't send a message to a user because of their privacy settings. How can I write my code to open a private channel, attempt sending a message, and handle not being able to send it?

Here is the code that sends the message:

```
public static void sendNotification(Warning warning, TextChannel alt) {
    User target = jda.getUserById(warning.getuId());
    if(target == null)
        return;
    target.openPrivateChannel().queue(c -> c.sendMessage(WarningUtil.generateWarningMessage(warning)).queue());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`flatMap`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) and [`onErrorFlatMap`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/requests/RestAction.html#onErrorFlatMap(java.util.function.Predicate,java.util.function.Function)):

```java
public RestAction<Message> sendMessage(User user, TextChannel context, String content) {
    return user.openPrivateChannel() // RestAction<PrivateChannel>
        .flatMap((channel) -> channel.sendMessage(content)) // RestAction<Message>
        .onErrorFlatMap(CANNOT_SEND_TO_USER::test,
            (error) -> context.sendMessage("Cannot send direct message to " + user.getAsMention())
        ); // RestAction<Message> (must be the same as above)
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`ErrorHandler`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/exceptions/ErrorHandler.html)

```java
public static void sendMessage(User user, String content) {
    user.openPrivateChannel()
        .flapMap(channel -> channel.sendMessage(content))
        .queue(null, new ErrorHandler()
            .handle(ErrorResponse.CANNOT_SEND_TO_USER,
                (ex) -> System.out.println("Cannot send message to user")));
}
```

Comment: I ended up using flatmaps sort of, your suggested feature was apparently removed in my version but it pointed me in the right direction

Comment: I think its the opposite and your version is too old and didn't get the feature yet it was added in 4.1.1_135

Comment: Oh, I was out of date! Thanks!